# wrong reference to home user shortcuts in 'unity launcher

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher

in my unity launcher the default `Files` icon points to the correct home directory;

but if I try to reach the standard folders (Desktop/ Downloads/ etc. -) through the right-click shortcut it points to a non (more) existing user ;

how can I update the reference to correct user in launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Is the path correct when you scroll over the library on the right side from nautilus? fix those by dragging the correct library to the right hand pane and then remove the incorrect one from there.

Comment: I'm talking about the quicklist reference

Comment: that right when you right click on the file manager icon right?

Comment: what i'm saying is, these shortcuts are linked to the left pane icons in the nautilus file manager, so when you change that you can change the shortcuts

Comment: the first thing I tried was  removing the entry an putting it back (through  dragging), but it didn't work; using `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` I can see that the the entry is `'application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop'`..

Comment: I'm not talking about the folder itself but in the file manager on the left pane there are a few shortcuts, these are the ones that are linked on the right click shortcuts. So changing them should fix this.

Comment: these are pointing to correct folders , the problem is within the launcher quicklist